# Maas nodes stuck on Deploying state

Tags: networking, juju, maas, openstack, cloud

I am using MAAS version `2.4.0 (6981-g011e51b7a-0ubuntu1~18.04.1)` on my setup. I have three Dell poweredge R420 servers. I have created 3 vms on each by using `virt-manager`. Allocated 8 Gb ram, 4 CPUs each. Using mactap bridge network on each for network access. I have successfully deployed `juju` on an old desktop. But when i deploy openstack on my whole setup. All of the machines get stuck on `Deploying` state and then maas shows `Failed deployment`.

So i have MAAS and juju on physical machines and have 9 vms on 3 dell servers. And i am trying to deploy openstack on vms.

Comment: Have you read through the all machines log on the juju server?